# Does dynamically updating a div with JS/jQuery rely on the click of an element on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div, or more specifically a `<p>` tag with `id="routineInfo"` I want to dynamically update on document.ready, but for some reason it does not seem to work:

```
$(function() {
  $("#routineInfo").html("Routine: Full Body");
});
```

I started troubleshooting and I could get the desired effect by attaching an onclick handle to an element to trigger the function:

```
$(".playIt").click(function() {
  $("#routineInfo").html("Routine: Full Body");
});
```

However, I wanted the function to happen on load of the desired page, so to simulate this I attached the handle to the element, found on a different page, that links to the page in question:

```
$(".linkElementOnDifferentPage").click(function() {
  $("#routineInfo").html("Routine: Full Body");
});
```

Did not work. Can anybody explain this to me please?

EDIT: adding html.

```
<div class="header">
  <div id="info">
    <p id="routineInfo"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first example should (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/468uwpjq/) work fine. The other two solutions are redundant in this case. Can you please set up a fiddle showing the issue. Is the `p` element dynamically loaded via AJAX?

Comment: please add your HTML. its hard to guess your problem with 100% working scripts.

Comment: Apologies Stavm, html added. @Rory McCrossan, Your js works indeed, but it just does not happen in my code. I wonder if some of my other functions are interfering with it.

Comment: is your 'div#routineInfo' rendered dynamically after the doc read function? If so you need to set the html only once the div is available inside the document(using setIntervel function or other methods).

Answer (score 0):

If your div(or p tag) is loaded dynamically, then it cannot be guarantied that its available at the document ready function(mostly in case of rendering views asynchronously).

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#info").append($('<p id="routineInfo"></p>'));
  }, 3000);
});
var DivPopulateIntervel = window.setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#routineInfo").length > 0) {
    $("#routineInfo").html("Routine: Full Body");
    window.clearInterval(DivPopulateIntervel);
  }
}, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div id="info">
  </div>
</div>
```

here

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#info").append($('<p id="routineInfo"></p>'));
}, 3000);
```

simply adds your `#routineInfo` to document after **3 seconds** to create a lazy loading or asynchronous effect(just for demo purpose).

```
var DivPopulateIntervel = window.setInterval(function() {
  if ($("#routineInfo").length > 0) {
    $("#routineInfo").html("Routine: Full Body");
    window.clearInterval(DivPopulateIntervel);
  }
}, 100);
```

is the `setInterval` function which gets called after every **100 milliseconds**, until the required div gets rendered.

```
window.clearInterval(DivPopulateIntervel);
```

removes the `DivPopulateIntervel` intervel function once the html is set(or the required div is available).